# How to document named tuple fields in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, documentation, namedtuple

When an API defines a named tuple, where would be the best place to document these fields?

Ideally so `MyType.__doc__` can be used to read back the information.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?